What episode of tom and jerry was this
Well... I don't remember much but I do remember some like the parts that Tom and Jerry were talking/speaking English and they were not chasing each other much, I think there was more action and talking but it was so long ago that I can't remember much. It looked like it was from the original series or close.
I remember one part where their house was going to be knocked down by, I think it was a wrecking ball and tom ran inside and got Jerry from his hole and ran for the car but it was too late (I think that's what happened, that's how I remember that part).
And I think it was longer then a normal episode so it might've been a special episode or just a long one (I can't remember how much longer or how long it was)

Can you see my answer and accept it if it's the right one. Thank you.

By reading your description, it's not an episode, it looks like the Tom & Jerry: The movie (1992), here's why:

While moving house with their owners, Tom and Jerry get into a chase, and Tom nails Jerry inside his mousehole with floorboards become pleased on keeping the mouse from coming with him, but misses the moving van and is forced to stay in the house after angering a nearby bulldog. The house is demolished the next morning with Tom going back inside to rescue Jerry, leaving them both homeless. Wandering through the city, they meet a dog, Puggsy, and his flea friend, Frankie, who try to persuade them to be friends. While finding food from some nearby bins for a feast, Puggsy and Frankie are captured by two dogcatchers, while Tom and Jerry end up in a tussle with some alley cats. They escape after Jerry fools them into falling into the sewer.

You can see the scene in this youtube video:



